# Discrepancies in `groups` output

Tags: debian, unix, groups, permissions

why is it that when I execute `groups` the output doesn't contain the *adm* group, while the output of `groups $USER` has it? The user is supposed to be in that group.

Comment: Similar to this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6387/how-to-add-write-permissions-for-a-group

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have just added a user to a group, you will need a log out and log back in in order to acquire the new credentials.  For example:

```
$ id
uid=500(lars) gid=500(lars) 
$ groups
lars
$ sudo usermod -G wheel,libvirt,mock lars
$ groups
lars
$ groups lars
lars : lars wheel libvirt mock
```

And if I log out and log back in:

```
$ groups
lars wheel libvirt mock
```